# Autorizar app en GitHub - NodeJS

Tags: nodejs

Buenas tardes, estoy intentando autorizar mi APP en NodeJS para poder hacer mas de 60 request a la GitHub API, consegui hacerlo mediante la autorizacion OAuth, lo cual al hacer un login enviando el client_id me devuelve el callback un acces_token, la cosa es. Asi ya quedaria autorizada la url de la app para hacer mas requests? O hay que hacer algo con el acces_token?

```
    var apiRequest = api('/repos/' + self.settings.org + '/' + self.repo + '/contents/package.json', {
        token: self.settings.gitToken
    });

    apiRequest.on('data', function(response) {
        self.reposParsed = JSON.stringify(allRepos);
        var packageJSON = new PackageJSON(self.settings, self.reposParsed);
        packageJSON.parseFromString(response.content, function(){
```

Esto es lo que hago basicamente para obtener el package.json del repo que seleccione. El tema es que este package carga muchas cosas y github me bloquea el acceso a la API porque para APPS no autorizadas solo permiten hacer 60 request por hora, lo que me gustaria saber es como autenticar mi APP en NodeJS con el acces_token que me genera github usando OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que registrar la app en github para que te dé el access token y poder usar la API sin tantas restricciones (pasarías de 60 request a 5000).

A continuación, te explico los pasos que tienes que realizar:

- Inicia sesión en [github](https://github.com/login).
- [Register a new OAuth application](https://github.com/settings/applications/new): Inserta los datos que te solicita y pulsa el botón de "Register application".
- [Basics of Authentication](https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/): Es una guía paso a paso. Aquí te explica como autenticarse además de referenciarte al enlace anterior. Sirve de turorial básico con un ejemplo de implementación en ruby.